# XCode CI: Post-action script times out in Bot

Tags: objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration, ui-automation, xcode-bots

I am running a post-action Archive script that executes UI Automation tests with a Bot on an OSX server. The script will take a very long time, greater than 30 minutes. The bot fails after about 5 minutes with the message:

"Bot Issue: error. Build Service Error.
Issue: Terminated xcodebuild since it produced no output for too long.."

Is there a way to increase the timeout setting? Or can the script be instructed to --trace a log file that is recording the results of the UI Automation tests to simulate output?